# How to handle subscriptions, applyBatchAfterware, and applyBatchMiddleware, in apollo-client 2.0?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

How are subscriptions, applyBatchAfterware, and applyBatchMiddleware, handled in apollo-client 2.0?

I would like to convert the following code, which I'm currently using in apollo-client 1.9.2, to be apollo-client 2.0 compliant:

```html
const logErrors = {
  applyBatchAfterware({ response }, next) {
    if (!response) return next();
    if (!response.ok) {
      response.clone().text().then((bodyText) => {
        console.log('...', `Network Error: ${response.status} (${response.statusText}) - ${bodyText}`);
        next();
      });
    } else {
      response.clone().json().then(({ errors }) => {
        if (errors) {
          console.log('...', 'GraphQL Errors:', errors.map(e => e.message));
        }
        next();
      });
    }
  },
};

const authMiddleware = {
  applyBatchMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {};
    }

    getStoredState({ storage: localForage }, (err, state = {}) => {
      req.options.headers['authorization'] = state.auth ? `Bearer ${state.auth.token}` : null;
      next();
    });
  }
}

const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient(SubscriptionClient_URL, {
  reconnect: true,
});

networkInterface.use([authMiddleware]);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  networkInterface.useAfter([logErrors]);
}

const networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions = addGraphQLSubscriptions(
  networkInterface,
  wsClient
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions,
  dataIdFromObject: (o) => o.id,
  addTypeName: true, 
});

networkInterface.setClient(client);

export default client;
```